# UseEffect endless loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm trying to learn why I have an endless loop with the following code. I'm using firebase to retrieve a single document.

```
import services from '../utilities/services';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

function SchoolDetail(){
    const {schoolID} = useParams();
    const [school, setSchool] = useState();
    const [id, setID] = useState(schoolID);
    


    useEffect(()=>{

        services.getSchool(schoolID).then((response) => {
            setSchool(response);
        }).catch((e) => {
            alert("Error occured while fetching the school. " + e);
        },[id])

    })

    return(
    <>
    {(school) && console.log(school.id)}
    Details
    </>
    );
}

export default SchoolDetail;.
```

I've tried using [] as the useEffect dependency and still get an endless loop.  I've tried [schoolID], and I've tried the state variable [id].  All cause an endless loop.  What am I missing?  Is is something to do with the getSchool function returning a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of an endless loop is caused by not passing a dependency array as the second argument of `useEffect`, and by setting the `id` state inside the `useEffect` callback, which triggers the `useEffect` to be called repeatedly.
To ensure that `useEffect` only runs once, on mount, you should pass an empty array as the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, []);
```

Moreover you can remove the `id` state and directly use `schoolID` as the dependency of useEffect:

```
const { schoolID } = useParams();
const [school, setSchool] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [schoolId]);
```

Comment: I've already tried both of those suggestions and neither worked.

Comment: Stupid problem.  I didn't have the dependency array on the useEffect function.  Looking at the parenthesis wrong